# Unable to render Griddlejs in an ajax:ModalPopupExtender?

Tags: webforms, reactjs, ajaxcontroltoolkit, modalpopupextender

Firstly, I apologise in advance, I'm very new to React and this is the first time I've implementing the Griddle component.

I am currently able to have a "Griddle" displaying successfully in a webforms solution, however, when I add the exact same griddle into a modalpopupextender it doesn't display and no error is thrown, the script is in the page if I inspect the div with the browser tools though.

I've put it into a control to test it in several areas of the so

- How may I accomplish this?
- Is there a way to delay the rendering of the griddle when the modalpopupextender is displaying?

  <%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Griddle.ascx.cs" Inherits="Website.UserControls.Griddle" %>

  ```
  <script type="text/jsx">
      var LinkComponent = React.createClass({
          render: function(){
              url = "speakers/" + this.props.rowData.lastName + "/" + this.props.data;
              return <a href={url}>{this.props.data}</a>
          }
      });

      var CheckBoxComponent = React.createClass({
          render: function(){
              checked = this.props.data;
              if(checked)
              {
                  return <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" />
              }
              else
              {
                  return <input type="checkbox" />
              }
          }
      });

      var ImageButtonComponent = React.createClass({
          render: function(){
              button = this.props.data;
              return <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ImageUrl="../images/action_addquicklist.png" CommandName="{button}" OnClick="ImageButton_Click" />
          }
      });

      var columnMeta = 
      [
          {
          "columnName":"lastName",
          "order":1,
          "locked":false,
          "visible":true,
          "customComponent": LinkComponent
          },
          {
          "columnName":"optedin",
          "order":1,
          "locked":false,
          "visible":true,
          "customComponent": CheckBoxComponent
          },
          {
          "columnName":"work",
          "order":1,
          "locked":false,
          "visible":true,
          "customComponent": ImageButtonComponent
          }
      ];

      var NoDataComponent = React.createClass({
          render: function(){
              return <div> <H1>No data is available</H1></div>
          }
      });
  </script>
  ```

Resources:
http://griddlegriddle.github.io/Griddle/index.html

To then display the Griddle on the page I do the following (though in a previous iteration the React.render section was in the control):

```
<div id="div1">
     <AppTest1:Griddle runat="server" ID="Griddle" />
               <script type="text/jsx">
                      React.render(
                            <Griddle
                            results={fakeData}
                            customNoDataComponent={NoDataComponent}
                            showSettings={true} 
                            showFilter={true} 
                            columnMetadata={columnMeta} 
                            columns={["firstName", "lastName", "email", "work", "age", "optedin"]}
                            />, 
                                                document.getElementById("griddle-basic")
                      );
               </script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the answer:

The reason that the Griddle component wasn't displaying was because the script in the code snippets above are in JSX, when I stepped through I found that the JSX code was being parsed appropriately, however, because the element to which the component is bound isn't visible at the time the page is hit and the JSX is transformed into Javascript, the component won't be displayed when the popup is triggered and the component is viewed.

The way I got around this was to manually transform the JSX scripts into Javascript prior to compilation and put it into a javascript function which is called when the ajax tab container's tab is switched in the ajax modal popup extender.

Due to my limited experience with JSX and React there is probably a better way, for example it would be worth seeing if you define an initial state for the Griddle component and then force a state change in the popup whether that would work or not but as it is my solution described above works exactly how I need it to for the moment.

[Here is a JSX to JS Compiler which I used.](https://facebook.github.io/react/jsx-compiler.html)